# SIGSEGV crash in iOS (Objective-C) at -[VPXDecoder decode:rawOutFrame:inFrameSize:frameInfo:]

Tags: ios, segmentation-fault, c2call

```
Incident Identifier: 64E7437E-C37F-425C-8582-18A14C43F95A
CrashReporter Key:   b90a1226375d6bce87d7c4fc6288d7951058aec4
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:             LolMess [428]
Path:                      /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B1A322EE-F140-49CB-B1D2-84601F0BE962/LolMess.app/LolMess
Identifier:          com.mobulous.LolMess
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-03-14 17:55:49.49 +0530
Launch Time:         2016-03-14 17:42:36.36 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      104

**Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)**
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0002c9f0
Triggered by Thread:  24

Filtered syslog:
None found

  Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
  Thread 0:
   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x245c0c24 mach_msg_trap + 20
  1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x245c0a28 mach_msg + 40
  2   CoreFoundation                    0x24903354     __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
  3   CoreFoundation                    0x249016dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
  4   CoreFoundation                    0x24854bf8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific +   520
   5   CoreFoundation                   0x248549e4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
  6   GraphicsServices                  0x25aa0ac8 GSEventRunModal + 160
 7   UIKit                          0x28ae4ba0 UIApplicationMain + 144
  8   LolMess                           0x002171d0 main (main.m:15)
  9   libdyld.dylib                     0x24503872 start + 2

  Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
   Thread 1:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x245d6320 kevent_qos + 24
  1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x244ce098 _dispatch_mgr_invoke +  256
   2   libdispatch.dylib                0x244cddf6    _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 38




 Thread 22:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x245c0c74 semaphore_wait_trap +     8
  1   LolMess                           0x0078ea9e thread_encoding_proc + 510
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x2467985a _pthread_body + 138
  3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x246797ce _pthread_start + 110
 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24677724 thread_start + 8

 Thread 23:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x245c0c74 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
   1   LolMess                          0x0078efda thread_loopfilter     + 54
   2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x2467985a _pthread_body + 138
  3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x246797ce _pthread_start + 110
  4   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x24677724 thread_start + 8

   Thread 24 Crashed:
  0   LolMess                           0x00781380 vp8_copy_mem16x16_neon + 16
  1   LolMess                           0x0077f828 vp8_build_inter16x16_predictors_mb + 188
  2   LolMess                           0x0077fa76 vp8_build_inter_predictors_mb + 414
 3   LolMess                        0x007a9f00 vp8_decode_frame + 11088
   4   LolMess                          0x007ab088 vp8dx_receive_compressed_data + 276
    5   LolMess                         0x007a537e vp8_decode + 1114
   6   LolMess                          0x007776ae vpx_codec_decode + 62
    7   LolMess                         0x007363ca -[VPXDecoder decode:rawOutFrame:inFrameSize:frameInfo:] (VPXDecoder.m:105)
    8   LolMess                         0x006f93ea -[RTPVideoHandler getDecodedVideoFrame:frameInfo:forStream:withOptions:] (RTPVideoHandler.m:1145)
      9   LolMess                           0x006f95ba -[RTPVideoHandler getDecodedVideoFrame:] (RTPVideoHandler.m:1184)
       10  LolMess                          0x00603b20 -[SCVideoCallController run:] (SCVideoCallController.m:896)
   11  Foundation                       0x25159164 __NSThread__start__ + 1148
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2467985a _pthread_body + 138
  13  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x246797ce _pthread_start + 110
   14  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x24677724 thread_start + 8

Error Formulating Crash Report:

Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
Using C2callSdk in app
```

Comment: Does SO look like a debugger?

Comment: Yes,Will you have any issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access a object already released from memory.

Check it by *Enabling NSZombie objects*, that will make compiler to stop at the line which causing crash.